# Boxing при интерполяции строк в c#

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Есть код 1

```
int i = 123;
string s = $"{i}";
```

И есть код 2

```
int i = 123;
string s = $"{i.ToString()}";
```

В первом варианте будет происходить боксинг или с интерполяцией не происходит такого и компилятор понимает что надо вызвать `ToString`?

Comment: Вохіng это замена определенной конкретной функции. А именно string.Format. Открывам MSDN и читаем https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx. Т.е. $"{i}" еквивалетно  string.Format("{0}",i) и так далее.

Comment: Боксинг будет происходить, потому что `string.Format` ожидает на входе массив, элементы которого имеют тип `object`. `i` будет приведено к `object`, и поскольку это значимый тип, он должен быть упакован. Во-втором случае бокнсинг не происходит, поскольку `string` и так является ссылочным типом.

Comment: Ещё тема $-обвёртки https://www.codingblocks.net/podcast/episode2/

Comment: Вохіng - я напутал, это не замена.  $  - заменяется на string.Format - и сразу ответ на вопрос становится очевидным.

Comment: @nick_n_a не становится. вопрос ведь такой "достаточно ли умный компилятор чтобы вставить ToString()". И насколько я знаю - недостаточно. А еще и решарпер свои палки в колеса ставит

Comment: @vitidev так в этом ведь и суть боксинга - примитивный тип при приведении к object - всегда проходит боксинг. А взлом (решарпер) -  отдельная тема на много страниц.

Comment: @nick_n_a да причем тут суть боксинга. вопрос в "вставит ли компилятор очевидную!!! оптимизацию или нет". А с решарпером другой вопрос "он предалгает удалять .ToString() как redundant  - не глупость ли это". Ответ на первый вопрос - нет, на второй - да

Comment: @vitidev  вы автор вопроса? Нет это правильно.

Comment: @nick_n_a нет. но  я вижу вопрос "и компилятор понимает что надо вызвать ToString?"

Comment: @vitidev Дождёмся пока спросит автор. А вам скажу, что двойное преобразование ToString+Format - излишнее.

Comment: Да я действительно хотел понять достаточно-ли умный компилятор что бы сделать очевидную оптимизацию. Спасибо всем кто принимал участие в ответе!

Comment: ToString+Format (двойное преобразование) - это менее оптимально чем boxing*+Format - одинарное преобразование. Подкачать может только boxing-так как он ест память, и то, ToString не хуже чем boxing требует память. ToString+Format - это действительно redundant - избыточное преобразование. Поэтому наоборот - нужно спрашивать, хватит ли компилятору вычислить что нужно Format+Boxing, потому что в Format уже заложена возможность преобразовывать числа. хотя... самый оптимальный вариант ToString - баз каких либо довесков вообще.

Comment: @nick_n_a ToString в любом случае будет вызван. Разница лишь в том, будет он сопровождаться боксингом. И вы сами себе противоречите. То у вас "boxing-так как он ест память", то тут же "ToString не хуже чем boxing требует память.". вариант без ToString = "плюс к выделению памяти для операции боксина ибо создание строки будет в обоих случаях"
и тс не первый поднимает вопрос https://habr.com/post/229741/ (пункт 1)

Comment: В пункт 1 ничего не сказано про тип integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)

```
string s = $"{i}";
```

превращается в string.format, который принимает object'ы, боксинг присутствует

[image: boxing]

2)

```
string s = $"{i.ToString()}";
```

передается строка, боксить нечего

[image: no boxing]

Comment: Надо бы бенчмарк, вдруг внутри int.ToString() есть тот же самый боксинг :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, там скорее вызов нативной функции идет

Comment: @Grundy, это я видел, но быстрее ли она, чем боксинг?

Comment: @АндрейNOP меня на это уже не хватит :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP а эта функция вызывается в обоих вариантах как бы

Comment: @АндрейNOP держите бенчмарк https://habr.com/post/70217/

Comment: @vitidev, да я уже сам прогнал: https://pastebin.com/1AVF6DQy

Comment: @tym32167 подскажите - с какого инструмента скины с IL?

Comment: @nikita LinqPad

Answer (score 0):

> В первом варианте будет происходить боксинг

Да.

> с интерполяцией не происходит такого и компилятор понимает что надо вызвать `ToString`?

Ваше утверждение "надо вызвать `ToString`" не является корректным, так как "надо" вызвать вовсе не тот `ToString`, который вызываете Вы.

```
using System;
class Test {
    struct S: IFormattable {
        public override string ToString() => "Object.ToString";
        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider) => "IFormattable.ToString";
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        S s = new S();
        Console.WriteLine($"{s}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{s.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/gRz74U

Так как поведение `String.Format` не является частью стандарта языка C#, то компилятор не имеет права выполнять, предложенную Вами, оптимизацию, так как он не может знать какой именно `ToString` нужно вызвать и с какими параметрами.

Более того, если определение типа `S` находится в другой сборке, то на этапе компиляции компилятор даже не будет иметь достаточного количества информации, чтобы определить, какой метод вызвать.